# network type not getting in iOS using Ionic native

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

We are developing an ionic native mobile application. we need network type (wifi,2g,3g,4g).We are getting in android but unable to get in iOS.We tried those commands for network plugins

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/network
```

Code

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      var networkState = this.network.type;
      alert("networktype"+JSON.stringify(this.network));
      console.log("networktype"+JSON.stringify(this.network));
    }, 30000);

    });
```

Always we are getting null in iOS. guide to us what we miss 
iOS version :10.3.3
ionic info :
[image: ionic info]

Comment: Testing with simulator or real device?

Comment: @DwlRathod real Device